# Select in ReactJS is picking up previous value after API call at onChange function?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-hooks

[image: Screenshot of the select and Input field]

Hi,
My requirement is that when a user selects an option for example: paper clip, the onChange function calls another function called getItem(), which makes API call and get current item details from database and stores it in currentItem variable. Now I want to update the unit price input box with the currentItem.unitPrice as soon as the user selects an option.
presently the unit price is getting updated with the value of previous selection not with the value of current selection. So, if I select paper clip nothing happens(null), but when I select second option(printer installation) it get updated with the prev value(unit price of paper clip)
I don't know what's going on please help.

```
 {inputList.map((x, i) => (
            <div className='form-group row'>
              <div className='input-group col-sm-2'>
<select
  className='form-control '
  name='item'
  value={x.item}
  onChange={(e) => handleInputChange(e, i)}
  required
>
  <option value='' disabled selected hidden>
    Item
  </option>
  {items.map((item) => (
    <option key={item._id} value={item._id}>
      {item.name}
    </option>
  ))}
</select>
```

```js
const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  const list = [...inputList];

  if (name === "item") {
    getItem(value);
    list[index]["unitPrice"] = currentItem && currentItem.unitPrice;
    setInputList(list);
  }

  list[index][name] = value;
  setInputList(list);
};


export const getItem = id => async dispatch => {
  try {
    const res = await axios.get(`/api/item/${id}`);

    dispatch({
      type: types.GET_ITEM,
      payload: res.data.data
    });
  } catch (err) {
    dispatch({
      type: types.ITEM_ERROR,
      payload: { msg: err.response.statusText, status: err.response.status }
    });
  }
};
```

Comment: I have updated the post, please have a look, it's actually array of fields that I am looping through so that user can add/remove input rows

Comment: @HenryLe it's where the the result of getItem() is stored getItem is basically an API call to get current item data, so it has got all the details of the currentItem which is selected, from there i need currentItem.unitPrice

Comment: I think the problem lies in getItem(value) in function handleInputChange. Can you show your function getItem

Comment: @HenryLe I have updated the post, please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (name === "item") {
    getItem(value);
    list[index]["unitPrice"] = currentItem && currentItem.unitPrice;
    setInputList(list);
  }
```

Because when select onchage the value currentItem is null (get api unfinnish). in the second onChange, currentItem has been successfully loaded previously, so it will retrieve data before currentItem

```js
const [selected, setSelected] = useState(-1);
const handleInputChange = (e, index) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  const { name, value } = e.target;
  let list = [...inputList];

  if (name === "item") {
    getItem(value);
  }
  setSelected(index)
  list[index][name] = value;
  setInputList(list);
};
useEffect(() => {
   if(currentItem._id){
      let list = [...inputList];
      list[selected]["unitPrice"] = currentItem.unitPrice;
      setInputList(list);
   }
}, [currentItem._id])
```